# Linkedlist keep track of min in constant time?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, linked-list

> EDIT:
>
> This isn't as trivial as
>   you think. Consider the fact that each
>   addition of a new number pushes out an
>   old number from the linkedlist.
>
> The solution doesn't seem to be as
>   simple as keeping track of a min
>   number with a variable. What if the
>   minimum gets pushed out of the
>   linkedlist? Then what? How do you know
>   what the new min is?

I heard this interview question:

You have a fixed length linked list.

- At time t=0, the linkedlist is filled
  with random numbers.
- At each increment in time, one new
  number is fed into the head of the
  linkedlist, and one number is pushed
  out from the tail.
- You are allowed only ONE traversal before the first time interval.

  - This means one traversal ever. **Not** once at every time t.
    .
- O(1) storage.

Your task is to be able to return the min of the linkedlist at every time interation.

What is an algorithm that would be able to do this?

---

**Interesting note:**

Since there's no information regarding time complexity, you are allowed to use sort operations. The only problem then is: sorting takes more than one iteration.

Comment: Sounds like homework but missing the homework tag

Comment: @Razor Storm - I am not being hasty but I will remove the homework tag.

Comment: This is trickier than it seems. Definitely not a homework.

Comment: @Razor no one said anything was wrong with it, take a chill pill brother...

Comment: Haha jon, I'm not angry, was just curious why you said that the question seemed to be given by HR. I thought I posted it wrong, and didn't realize that it could be misinterpreted as something very trivial. :)

Comment: @Razor Storm - no my bad on that one, I thought one traversal meant at each Time `t` iteration, than it would be a breeze.  But it appears you can only do it `ONCE`, so let me get back to my drawing board :).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought at first too when I first heard it. (I actually didn't get asked this in a personal interview, was actually relayed this question from a friend at an amazon interview) I'm 100% positive if my friend gave me the exactly right specifications, since this seems impossible as it stands. I'm probably thinking about it wrong though... =/

Comment: @Razor Storm - Did amazon mention this was possible or just left it in the air?  Because this doesn't seem to be feasible given the requirements.

Comment: @jonH, that's my conclusion as well. I'll ask my friend if he remembers more details

Comment: This rather poorly posed question would seem to be impossible to answer.

Comment: @Razor Storm - Odd he / she didn't tell you this...but to be quite honest from this information off of a linked list this doesn't seem possible, unless you can sort the list, which of course you did not mention.

Comment: If it makes things clearer, you can simplify "one traversal ever" to "one traversal before the first time interval". Clearly you need a traversal in order to report the minimum the first time - unless the list contains `INT_MIN` or equivalent, you have to look at every value or else you might have missed the minimum. So there's no need to allow any uncertainty about when this permitted traversal occurs...

Comment: I guess the moral of the story here is we all aren't valid candidates to work at Amazon.com :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First,

> O(1) storage is not the same as an a single register. It means constant space usage.

Second,

> I am going to call your LL a constant size queue (CSQ).

When initializing your queue, also initialize a min-heap where all elements of the queue keep a reference (pointer) to the heap node corresponding to them.

#### 1 op on CSQ

- Pop 1 element out in O(1) time of the CSQ.
- Remove corresponding node from the min-heap in [O(lg n) time](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node138.html).
- Add corresponding element to the min-heap in [O(lg n) time](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node138.html).
- Push 1 element into the CSQ in O(1) time and mark a reference to the heap node added above.

The above operations guarentee that the heap size will always remain in sync with the queue size --hence O(1). The heap can be constructed in a single travesal.

#### Finding min

Clearly O(1). Just return the head of the min heap.

Comment: Alike most of the answers here, this relies on the assumption that "fixed length" refers to N will always be the same. In that case, this is a great solution.

Comment: @Razor, As long as you push one element in the queue and one element comes out of the queue because of the push, that assumption should hold true. These types of queues are common in mainframe job schedulers.

Comment: why is the smallest element always first?

Comment: @BlackBear, Because it is a [min-heap](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node137.html).

Comment: haha I meant that this relies on the assumption that having an auxiliary structure of size lengthOfLinkedList is considered constant O(1). That is most likely true though, since otherwise this problem would have no solution.

Comment: Great Solution :-). Sweet, tidy and simple

Answer (score 0):

First off, a LL is usually used for dynamic sizes. You would probably want a regular array for fixed-size since, once again usually, it will take up less memory.

Second, you seem to have more of a queue than a list, which means when you push an element in you pop one out. In that case, the minimum can be constantly changing. Naively you can search for the minimum in any 1D list in O(n) time.

Less naively, your LL could also be a pre-sorted (sort-on-insert) heap, in which case finding the minimum element can be O(1) (depending on the structure chosen). However, insert will take O(n) time.

I am aware this does not answer your question, but this really sounds like a homework question. Use this as a guide/reference/help for your problem. :)

Hope everything gets solved, and I hope I helped!

Comment: as mentioned by OP this is not homework, it sounds pretty valid.  Second this would not work as first of all you cannot sort it as was mentioned in the post.

Comment: You're right. That'll teach me to answer questions at work :p I'll lrn2read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one posted this (so it's probably wrong), but (pseudocode):

```
struct abc                                    // sorry for the name :)
{
    int pos
    int num
}
initialize
{
    struct abc min_array[linked_list_length];   // O(1) space

    fill(min_array, linked_list_elements);      // place every element in the array
    sort(min_array);                            // sort in ascending order, the sorting
                                                // compares num
}

insert_element
{
    linked_list.push(value);
    linked_list.pop();

    for each element in min_array {
        element.pos += 1

        if element.pos > linked_list.elementCount then   // this was popped out!
            element.pos = 1;
            element.num = value;
        end if
    }

    sort(min_array);        // as before, sorting compares only num
}

get_min_value
{
    return min_array[0];
}
```

Comment: @BlackBear - you cannot sort it.\

Comment: I think it's "cheating" to call your array O(1) space. I believe the size of the linked list is intended to be "fixed" in the sense that it doesn't change over the course of the operations described, not "fixed" in the sense of asymptotically constant. The big-O analysis is (I believe) intended to be performed w.r.t the limit as the size of the linked list approaches infinity.

Comment: @JonH: the OP doesn't say that

Comment: @Steve Jessop: see the OP's answer :P

Comment: @BlackBear - I assume that if the values are randomized it means you cannot sort them.  @Razor Storm if this is sortable you should of mentioned that as sorting this would of made it really easy :).

Comment: @BlackBear: hmm. I guess I can't accuse the questioner of misunderstanding his own question, but I can accuse him of misunderstanding the question originally posed ;-)

Comment: Don't take my answer as a holy grail, it is most likely not even valid. I was just throwing something out there that I noticed. @Steve Jessop, yup  exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution I can have is through a technicality:

Since the size of the linkedlist is fixed at the time of WRITING, that means N is constant. In that case, we are technically allowed to store an auxiliary structure that is a direct copy of the linkedlist (perhaps in an array). This is O(1) storage since N is constant.

Comment: This feels like exploitation of a loophole, but I don't think the question is solveable in any other way.

Comment: I think in the future if you post stuff like this, give us more details like allowable operations / functions such as sorting or copying.

Comment: @JonH, yeah my bad about the vagueness of the question. I'm not too sure about the specifics myself. I am not saying my answer is right or even valid. Actually it most likely isnt =[

Comment: Using my test taking skills here :D. Why else would the interviewer say O(1) storage? So I believe your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, this is a queue, implemented as a linked list (correct me if I am wrong).
To solve this, I would just change the idea of the node. A typical node will have next pointer and a value. Change this to have three elements, nextPointer, value and minSoFar. If you don't like the idea of changing the queue design, still, read this algo and I have provided another idea at the end.

I think this can be done in **O(1)** The trick is while traversing the list, keep track of the smallest element encountered until that point in the list and store it in the current node. So, for example you have the following queue

Head at **5** and tail at **13**

**5 |7 |6 |9 |5 |13 |**

My modified queue will contain the nodes like

**{5,5}|{7,6}|{6,6}|{9,9}|{13,13}| ({nodeVal, minSoFar})**

Now, consider an operation, adding 3 to the queue and removing 13, the queue becomes

**{3,3}|{5,5}|{7,6}|{6,6}|{9,9}|**

Since 3 is less than the current head element, the min so far for the head element is its value

Consider another case where you need to add 15 to the queue

**{15,5}|{5,5}|{7,6}|{6,6}|{9,9}|**

Since 15 is greater than the current head element, the current minimum value becomes 5.

So to find the minimum element in the queue/list, all you need to do is check the head element and your time complexity will be O(1)

**If you don't want to modify the queue, maintain a parallel queue and keep the minValueSoFar in that queue and mirror the operations in that queue.**

Comment: Close, but you need to account for what happens when you push the minimum out of the queue. For example, if your queue is [3,2,1] and you add 4 and extract 1, you get [4,3,2]. The old answer, 1, is invalid; you need to be able to find 2 in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

If node can be defined as follows, then solution is simple:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node prevMin;
}
```